Real-time collaborative editing with editor.js
I'm working on a project involving collaborative text editing with Editor.js and could use some help with a couple of issues:
I'm trying to integrate Editor.js with libraries like Yjs or ShareDB for conflict resolution using CRDT or OT.
Whenever I update a block in Editor.js, it flashes and rerenders, causing the user to lose focus on the text field.
this is my current code:
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';
import Header from '@editorjs/header';
import Checklist from '@editorjs/checklist'
import RawTool from '@editorjs/raw';
import './css.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './toolBarcss.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faStrikethrough, faBold, faItalic, faUnderline } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import SketchExample from './SketchExample';
import Underline from '@editorjs/underline';
import Strikethrough from 'editorjs-strikethrough';
import { SimpleImage } from './simpleimage';
import Video from '@weekwood/editorjs-video';


export const EditorContext = createContext()
let blockid = null;
let blockElement = null;
let data = null;
let selectedText = null;
let startPosition = null;
let endPosition = null;
function Editor(props) {

  const editorInstanceRef = useRef(null)
  const initEditor = () => {
    const editor = new EditorJS({
      readOnly: false,
      holder: "editorjs",
      placeholder: "Let's take a note!",
      tools: {
        image: {
          class: SimpleImage,
          config: {
            endpoints: {
              byFile: 'http://localhost:8008/uploadFile', // Your backend file uploader endpoint
              byUrl: 'http://localhost:8008/fetchUrl', // Your endpoint that provides uploading by Url
            }
          },

          actions: [
            {
              name: 'new_button',
              icon: '<svg>...</svg>',
              title: 'New Button',
              toggle: true,
              action: (name) => {
                alert(`${name} button clicked`);
              }
            }
          ]
        }, video: {
          class: Video,
          config: {
            endpoints: {

            }
          }
        },

        strikethrough: {
          class: Strikethrough,
          shortcut: 'CMD+SHIFT+X',
        },
        underline: Underline,
        header: {
          class: Header,
          config: {
            placeholder: 'Enter a header',
            levels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            defaultLevel: 1,
            shortcut: 'CMD+SHIFT+H',
          }
        },
        raw: {
          class: RawTool,
          inlineToolbar: false,
        },
        checklist: {
          class: Checklist,
          inlineToolbar: false,
        }
      },
      onChange: async () => {
        data = await editor.save();
      }

    })
    editorInstanceRef.current = editor
    const editorContainer = document.getElementById('editorjs');
    editorContainer.addEventListener('click', handleBlockClick);
    editorContainer.addEventListener('mouseup', selectionevent);
  }


  /**
   * Handles the user selection event within an editor block.
   * This function determines the closest block element based on the event target,
   * retrieves the selected text and its start and end positions within the block,
   * and gets the index of the current block in the editor.
   * 
   * @param {Event} event - The event object triggered by the user action.
   */

  const selectionevent = async (event) => {
    const closestBlock = event.target.closest('.ce-block');
    let blockElement, blockId;
    if (closestBlock) {
      blockElement = closestBlock;
      blockId = blockElement.getAttribute('data-id');
    } else {
      blockElement = null;
      blockId = null;
    }
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selectedText = selection.toString();
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
    preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(blockElement);
    preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
    startPosition = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

    // Adjust endPosition by excluding the length of the selectedText itself
    endPosition = startPosition + selectedText.length;
    index = editorInstanceRef.current.blocks.getCurrentBlockIndex();

  };





  ////// add bold italic underline or color to selected text ////////


  /**
   * Changes the color of a font element in the HTML content.
   * This function takes a color value as input and generates opening and closing tags
   * for a font element with the specified color style. It then calls the changeStyle function
   * to apply the color change to the HTML content.
   * 
   * @param {string} data - The color value to apply (e.g., "red", "#00ff00", "rgb(255, 0, 0)").
   */
  const changeColor = (data) => {
    const word = "font"
    const open = `<font style="color: ${data};">`
    const close = '</font>'
    changeStyle(word, open, close);
  };


  /**
   * Removes empty HTML tags from the given text content.
   * This function parses the HTML text using DOMParser, removes all empty tags,
   * and returns the cleaned HTML text without empty tags.
   * 
   * @param {string} text - The HTML text content to clean.
   * @returns {string} - The cleaned HTML text without empty tags.
   */
  const cleanHTMLTags = (text) => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
    const emptyTags = doc.querySelectorAll(':empty');
    emptyTags.forEach((tag) => tag.parentNode.removeChild(tag));
    const cleanedText = doc.body.innerHTML;
    return cleanedText;
  };



  /**
   * Adds style tags (bold italic underline and strike) around the selected text in the block content
   *  using the changestyle function.
   */
  const addstyle = (word) => {
    const startTime = performance.now();
    const open = `<${word}>`;
    const close = `</${word}>`;
    changeStyle(word, open, close);
    const endTime = performance.now();
    const elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
  }

  /**
 * This function is responsible for modifying the styling of the selected text in the block content.
 * It take in consideration multiple cases lets take bold for example 
 * it will start by splitting the text and Iterate through the full html text to determine left, middle, and right portions 
 * after that it perform checks on the right left and middle to determine which case are we in 
 * I have 5 cases for example when I press the bold button:
 * if I have a text "123456789"       and I select "2345678"  we are in the last case which is simple adding 
 * if I have a text "1<b>2345678<b>9" and I select "2345678"  we are in case 3 which is removing the <b></b>
 * if I have a text "1<b>2345678<b>9" and I select "45678"    we are in case 3 which is changing the </b> position
 * if I have a text "1<b>2345678<b>9" and I select "23456"    we are in case 4 which is changing the <b> position
 * if I have a text "1<b>2345678<b>9" and I select "45"       we are in case 4 which is adding the </b> before "45" and adding <b> after
 * 
 * those are the common cases but sometimes I got other cases like case 1 and 2 
 * note all cases except the adding are not applied for the font tag
 * 
 */
  const changeStyle = async (word, open, close) => {
    let left = '';
    let midle = '';
    let right = '';
    let leftResult;
    let midleResult;
    let rightResult;

    // Start and end positions for text modification
    let a = startPosition;
    let b = endPosition;

    // Ensure a <= b because when I select a text from right to left they switch 
    if (a > b) {
      a = startPosition;
      b = startPosition;
    }

    // Check if blockid is provided and fetch updated data
    if (blockid) {
      const updatedData = data;
      const currentBlock = updatedData.blocks.find((block) => block.id === blockid);

      // If the current block is found
      if (currentBlock) {
        let currentText = currentBlock.data.text;

        /**  Split the full html text with the tags into an array for processing 
        *     example text:"123456789" html text: "123<b>456</b>789"
        */
        const textArray = currentText.split('');
        let skipMode = false;

        // Iterate through the full html text to determine left, middle, and right portions 
        for (let i = 0; i < textArray.length && i < b; i++) {
          if (i === b) {
            break;
          }

          if (textArray[i] === '<') {
            skipMode = true;
          }

          if (skipMode && i <= a) {
            a++;
            b++;
          }

          if (skipMode && i > a) {
            b++;
          }

          if (textArray[i] === '>') {
            skipMode = false;
          }
        }

        // Extract left, middle, and right portions of the text
        left = currentText.substring(0, a)
        midle = currentText.substring(a, b)
        right = currentText.substring(b)

        // Perform checks and modifications based on the left, middle, and right portions
        leftResult = checkLeft(left, word)
        midleResult = countAndSubtractTags(midle, word)
        rightResult = checkright(right, word)

        // Construct modifiedText based on the checks and results
        if (leftResult.check && rightResult.check && word !== "font") {
          console.log("case 1")
          const modifiedText = [
            leftResult.text,
            midleResult.text,
            rightResult.text
          ].join('');
          currentBlock.data.text = cleanHTMLTags(modifiedText);
        } else if (leftResult.check && !rightResult.check && word !== "font") {
          console.log("case 2")
          const modifiedText = [
            leftResult.text,
            midleResult.text,
            rightResult.storedOpenTags,
            rightResult.text
          ].join('');
          currentBlock.data.text = cleanHTMLTags(modifiedText);
        } else if (!leftResult.check && rightResult.check && word !== "font") {
          console.log("case 3")
          const modifiedText = [
            leftResult.text,
            rightResult.CloseTag,
            midleResult.text,
            rightResult.text
          ].join('');
          currentBlock.data.text = cleanHTMLTags(modifiedText);
        } else if (!leftResult.check && !rightResult.check && leftResult.CloseTag && rightResult.storedOpenTags && word !== "font") {
          console.log("case 4")
          if (word === "font") {
            midleResult.text = open + midleResult.text + close;
          }
          const modifiedText = [
            leftResult.text,
            leftResult.CloseTag,
            midleResult.text,
            rightResult.storedOpenTags,
            rightResult.text
          ].join('');
          currentBlock.data.text = cleanHTMLTags(modifiedText);
        } else {
          console.log("case adding")
          const modifiedText = [
            currentText.substring(0, a),
            midleResult.storedCloseTags,
            open,
            midleResult.text,
            close,
            midleResult.storedOpenTags,
            currentText.substring(b)
          ].join('');
          currentBlock.data.text = cleanHTMLTags(modifiedText);
        }
      }

      // Render the updated data in the editor
      editorInstanceRef.current.render(updatedData);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Analyzes the left part of a text string in HTML content for a specified word.
   * This function looks for the last occurrence of the opening tag and the corresponding
   * closing tag related to the specified word in the text. It handles tags and modifies
   * the text accordingly, providing information about found tags and any modifications made.
   * 
   * @param {string} text - The input text string to be analyzed.
   * @param {string} word - The specified word that the function focuses on in the text.
   * @returns {Object} An object containing storedOpenTags, CloseTag, modified text, and check flag.
   * - storedOpenTags: Any opening tags related to the specified word found in the text.
   * - CloseTag: The closing tag related to the specified word.
   * - text: The modified text after tag processing.
   * - check: A flag indicating whether modifications were made to the text (true/false).
   */
  function checkLeft(text, word) {
    let storedOpenTags = '';
    let CloseTag = '';
    let check = false;

    // Check if the input text is not empty
    if (text !== '') {
      let startIndex = text.length - 1;
      let endIndex = text.length;

      // Iterate backwards through the text to find the last occurrence of the opening tag of the word
      while ((startIndex = text.lastIndexOf('<' + word[0], startIndex)) !== -1) {
        // Find the corresponding closing tag for the word
        endIndex = text.indexOf(word[word.length - 1] + '>', startIndex);

        // If no closing tag is found, break the loop
        if (endIndex === -1) {
          break;
        }

        // Extract the tag from startIndex to endIndex
        const tag = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1);

        // Check if the tag is a closing tag for the word
        if (tag.startsWith('</' + word)) {
          // If it's a closing tag, break the loop
          break;
        } else if (tag.startsWith('<' + word)) {
          // If it's an opening tag, store it as the storedOpenTags
          storedOpenTags = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1);

          // Check if the opening tag is at the end of the text
          if (endIndex + 1 === text.length) {
            // If yes, remove the tag from the text and set check to true
            text = text.substring(0, startIndex);
            check = true;
            break;
          } else {
            // If not, set the CloseTag and break the loop
            CloseTag = '</' + word + '>';
            break;
          }
        }
        // Move to the previous character in the text
        startIndex--;
      }
    }

    // Return an object containing the storedOpenTags, CloseTag, modified text, and check flag
    return { storedOpenTags, CloseTag, text, check };
  }


  /**
   * Analyzes the right part of a text string in HTML content for a specified word.
   * This function looks for opening and closing tags related to the specified word
   * in the right part of the text. It handles tags and modifies the text accordingly,
   * providing information about found tags and any modifications made.
   * 
   * @param {string} text - The input text string to be analyzed.
   * @param {string} word - The specified word that the function focuses on in the text.
   * @returns {Object} An object containing storedOpenTags, CloseTag, modified text, and check flag.
   * - storedOpenTags: Any opening tags related to the specified word found in the text.
   * - CloseTag: The closing tag related to the specified word.
   * - text: The modified text after tag processing.
   * - check: A flag indicating whether modifications were made to the text (true/false).
   */
  function checkright(text, word) {
    // Initialize variables to store open tags, closing tags, and a check flag
    let storedOpenTags = '';
    let CloseTag = '';
    let startIndex = 0;
    let endIndex = 0;
    let check = false;

    // Iterate through the text to find opening and closing tags related to the specified word
    while ((startIndex = text.indexOf('<', endIndex)) !== -1 && endIndex != text.length) {
      // Find the index of the closing '>' character
      endIndex = text.indexOf('>', startIndex);

      // If no closing tag is found, break the loop
      if (endIndex === -1) {
        break;
      }

      // Extract the tag from startIndex to endIndex
      const tag = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1);

      // Check if the tag is a closing tag for the specified word
      if (tag.startsWith('</' + word)) {
        // If it's a closing tag, check if it's at the begining of the text
        if (tag.length === endIndex + 1) {
          // If yes, remove the tag from the text and set CloseTag and check flags
          text = text.substring(endIndex + 1, text.length);
          CloseTag = tag;
          check = true;
        } else {
          // If it's not the entire tag, set CloseTag and storedOpenTags accordingly
          CloseTag = tag;
          storedOpenTags = '<' + word + '>';
        }
        // Break the loop after processing the closing tag
        break;
      } else if (tag.startsWith('<' + word)) {
        // If it's an opening tag, break the loop
        break;
      }
      endIndex++; // Move to the next '>' character
    }

    // Return an object containing the stored open tags, CloseTag, modified text, and check flag
    return { storedOpenTags, CloseTag, text, check };
  }



  /**
   * Counts and subtracts opening and closing tags related to a specified word in the text.
   * This function iterates through the text to find and process tags (opening and closing)
   * related to the specified word. It counts the occurrences of opening and closing tags,
   * subtracts them based on certain conditions, and handles tag removal and storage.
   * 
   * @param {string} text - The input text string to be analyzed for tags.
   * @param {string} word - The specified word that the function focuses on in the text.
   * @returns {Object} An object containing storedOpenTags, storedCloseTags, and modified text.
   * - storedOpenTags: Any opening tags related to the specified word found in the text.
   * - storedCloseTags: Any closing tags related to the specified word found in the text.
   * - text: The modified text after tag processing.
   */
  function countAndSubtractTags(text, word) {
    // Initialize variables to store open tags, closing tags, and flags
    let storedOpenTags = '';
    let storedCloseTags = '';
    let closedtag = false;
    let startIndex = 0;
    let endIndex = 0;
    let startopen = false;
    let countWord1 = (text.match(new RegExp('<' + word, 'g')) || []).length;
    let countWord2 = (text.match(new RegExp('</' + word + '>', 'g')) || []).length;

    // Iterate through the text to find and process tags related to the specified word
    while ((startIndex = text.indexOf('<', endIndex)) !== -1) {
      endIndex = text.indexOf('>', startIndex);
      if (endIndex === -1) {
        break; // Break the loop if no closing '>' character is found
      }

      const tag = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1);

      if (tag.startsWith('</' + word)) {
        // Handle closing tags
        if (!startopen) {
          // If it's the first closing tag encountered, store it in storedCloseTags
          closedtag = true;
          storedCloseTags += text.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1);
        }
        // Remove the tag from the text and update counters
        text = text.slice(0, startIndex) + text.slice(endIndex + 1);
        startIndex = 0;
        endIndex = 0;
        countWord2--;
      } else if (tag.startsWith('<' + word)) {
        // Handle opening tags
        startopen = true;
        if (countWord2 > 0) {
          // If closing tags are still present, decrement the opening tag counter
          countWord1--;
        } else if (countWord1 > 0 && countWord2 <= 0) {
          // If no closing tags are left but opening tags are present, store in storedOpenTags
          storedOpenTags += text.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1);
          closedtag = false;
        }
        // Remove the tag from the text and reset indices
        text = text.slice(0, startIndex) + text.slice(endIndex + 1);
        startIndex = 0;
        endIndex = 0;
      }
    }

    // Return an object containing the stored open tags, stored close tags, and modified text
    return { storedOpenTags, storedCloseTags, text };
  }

  ////// end of add bold italic underline or color to selected text ////////





  ////// when block is clicked ////////
  const handleBlockClick = async (event) => {
    const closestBlock = event.target.closest('.ce-block');
    if (closestBlock) {
      blockElement = closestBlock;
      blockid = blockElement.getAttribute('data-id');
    } else {
      blockElement = null;
      blockid = null;
    }
  };
  ////// end of when block is clicked ////////


  return (
    <>

      <div className="container">
        <div className="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
          <button onClick={() => addstyle('b')} type="button" className="btn btn-light btn-sm">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBold} />
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => addstyle('i')} type="button" className="btn btn-light btn-sm">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faItalic} />
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => addstyle('u')} type="button" className="btn btn-light btn-sm">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUnderline} />
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => addstyle('strike')} type="button" className="btn btn-light btn-sm">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStrikethrough} />
          </button>
          <SketchExample onData={changeColor} />
        </div>

      </div>


      <EditorContext.Provider value={{ initEditor, editorInstanceRef }}>
        {props.children}

      </EditorContext.Provider>

    </>

  )
}
export default Editor;


Your code is pretty complex and unfortunately I can't debug it without the missing pieces, but I wrote a collaborative editor.js interface in plain JavaScript using OT (ShareDB), which doesn't have the issues you're struggling with, has some nice animation, and shows cursors of multiple users. It's very simple and few lines of code in total. Perhaps it will be useful to you?
https://github.com/onexdata/realtime-editor.js
